# Default GCS bucket name

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/activate:

> The default bucket name is typically <app_id>.appspot.com, where you
>   replace  with your app ID. You can find the bucket name in the
>   App Engine Admin console Application Settings page, under the label
>   Google Cloud Storage Bucket. Alternatively, you can use the App
>   Identity get_default_gcs_bucket_name() method to find the name
>   programmatically.

When I look under the label Google Cloud Storage Bucket, I see `<app-id>.appspot.com`, where `<app-id>` is my application's identifier. That seems consistent with the first two sentences in the paragraph above.

But when I call `get_default_gcs_bucket_name()` as suggested in the final sentence, the return value is `app_default_bucket`.

Since I deploy this app to several sites, I'd like to use the method call. Is there anyway to get it to return the real default bucket name?

Comment: Are you testing this in the SDK or deployed?

Comment: @Greg SDK. I haven't tried deploying yet. By the way, since your question suggests you have some experience with this, I'd be grateful if you'd also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406633/running-gae-gcs-on-pycharm-under-os-x-runtime-error-no-module-named-cloudstora

Comment: I've had issues using the GCS plug int he dev server. Try deploying it and see what you get.

Comment: @Greg @Bruyere I tried deploying but got "No module named cloudstorage" (see thread mentioned above). So I commented out the killer import statement and its dependencies, and good news, `get_default_gcs_bucket_name()` worked correctly. That resolves this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Most services are replaced with stub in the development environment. Once you deploy the app to GAE, get_default_gcs_bucket_name will return `<app_id>.appspot.com`.

I verified the behavior with the following app:

```
import webapp2

from google.appengine.api import app_identity


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write(app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the client library with the development server. However because there is no local emulation of Cloud Storage, all requests to read and write files must be sent over the Internet to an actual Cloud Storage bucket.

To use the client library with the development app server:

Activate a Cloud Storage bucket.

**Run dev_appserver.py with the flag --default_gcs_bucket_name [BUCKET_NAME]**, replacing [BUCKET_NAME] with the name of the Cloud Storage bucket you are using.

This flag controls the bucket that will be returned when your application calls file.DefaultBucketName(ctx).

Found this in the google docs -
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#activating_a_cloud_storage_bucket