# What, specifically, is the <your_app_directory> when pip installing GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient?

Tags: python, macos, pip, google-cloud-storage

When following the install instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/download), what, specifically, is the `<your_app_directory>` in:

```
pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t <your_app_directory/lib>
```

?

I have tried:

1. /Applications folder
2. the home folder hosting my .py files that I'm running on GAE
3. same as (2) under the venv subfolder

However I'm getting:

ImportError: No module named cloudstorage

if I try:

```
import cloudstorage as gcd
```

and:

ImportError: No module named lib.cloudstorage

if I try:

```
import lib.cloudstorage as gcd
```

with all the above.

E.g.

```
>>> os.listdir("/applications/lib") 
['cloudstorage', 'GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient-1.9.15.0-py2.7.egg-info']
>>> import lib.cloudstorage 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: No module named lib.cloudstorage
>>>
```

Comment: it should be in your /Applications/lib.

Comment: @Patrice: Doesn't seem to be the case, as I'm getting this:             >>> os.listdir("/applications/lib")
['cloudstorage', 'GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient-1.9.15.0-py2.7.egg-info']
>>> import lib.cloudstorage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lib.cloudstorage
>>>

Comment: @zanzu `lib` itself is _not_ a package (it has no `__init__.py` file), thus you can't do `import lib.cloudstorage`. As you've found out you can however add the whole folder to your python path (which tells python where to search for modules and packages), and then do `import cloudstorage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what did it at the end, but I no longer get the import error after doing:

```
sys.path.append('/applications/lib')
```

Answer (score 1):

`<your_app_directory>` is the path to the folder containing your `app.yaml` file.

Your YAML file specifies a script file containing your GAE `handlers`. This script file, YAML file, and dependencies need to be packaged into a folder for [upload](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appcfg-arguments).

I use this folder structure:

- app/

  - app.yaml  `Note: script attribute will point to src.main.application`
  - src/

    - `__init__.py`
    - main.py  `Contains a variable called application`
  - mypackage/

    - `__init__.py`
    - supermodule.py
    - othermodule.py
  - lib/

    - cloudstorage/
    - otherlib/
    - etc/

To help python find modules in sub-folders, like the usage `import cloudstorage as gcs`, the following code is useful in your `main.py` file:

```
import os
import sys
#sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "lib"))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."), "lib"))  # relative to main.py
```